# Non-meromorphic counterpart of $\Gamma (z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

The gamma function is the only meromorphic function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $zf(z)=f(z+1)$, $f(1)=1$ and which is logarithmically convex on the positive real axis.

Does there exist a **non-meromorphic** function $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $zf(z)=f(z+1)$, $f(1)=1$ and which is logarithmically convex on the postitive real axis?

Comment: Nitpick: there's no such thing as a non-meromorphic function. "Meromorphic function" is a self-contained concept; most meromorphic functions are not functions on $\mathbb C$ in the usual sense.

Comment: Meromorphic functions are allowed to have poles.  For example, $\Gamma(z)$ itself has a pole at $z=0$.  When the OP wants to talk about non-meromorphic functions, he should explain what sort of singularities will be allowed.  As Fred showed, "defined everywhere with values in $\mathbb C$" won't work.  Maybe we can ask about domain $\mathrm{Re}\;z > 0$, for example.

Comment: @GEdgar Actually, I wanted to know whether the word *meromorphic* is superfluous when we uniquely characterize the gamma function using my first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a function such that $zf(z)=f(z+1)$ and $f(1)=1.$ Then we get

$$1=f(0+1)=0 \cdot f(0)=0.$$

Conclusion ?

Comment: Are you sure that $0\cdot f(0)=0$? $f(z)$ has a pole at $z=0$, so definitely we don't get $0\cdot f(0)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand how is that supposed to answer my question.

Comment: @PoderRac Meromorphic functions have poles. Functions do not have poles. What exactly do you mean by *non-meromorphic function*?

Comment: @John A function that has poles but also has jump discontinuities.